# Reverse a linkedList does not work

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to reverse a linked list in Java.
Here is my code.

```
class Node{ 
    int value; Node next; 
    Node(int value){ this.value = value; } 
} 

class LinkedList{

 Node head;

 void push(int value){
        Node new_node = new Node(value);
        new_node.next = head;
        head = new_node;
        System.out.println("new head is"+head.value);
    }

void reverseList(Node node){
        Node iter = node;
        Node prev = null;
        while(iter!=null){
            Node currentNext = iter.next;
            iter.next = prev;
            prev = iter;
            iter = currentNext;
        }
        node = prev;
    }
// To print the list referred by this node.
void printList(Node node){
        Node iter = node;
        while(iter!=null){
            System.out.print(" "+iter.value);
            iter = iter.next;
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

In main(),

```
LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
list.push(3);
list.push(2);
list.push(1); 
list.printList();// linked list is 1->2->3
list.reverseList(list.head);
list.printList(list.head); // Output is 1
```

Why is the list not printing in the correct orde (3->2->1) after reversing the list?

Comment: What's the debugger tell you?

Comment: "Java pass by reference" Stop right there. It isn't. There is no such thing in Java. See the duplicate.

Comment: @cricket_007 Are you kidding? That's all the question is *about.* Pass by reference. Why on earth is this reopened?

Comment: @EJP I think the question is actually "why the fully reversed list is not printed". While the problem may originate from pass by reference, that duplicate doesn't answer anything about linked lists

Comment: @cricket_007 The question is answered by refuting the assumption abuot pass-by-reference.

Answer (score 0):

You reversed the list without reseting the head.

Your print reference is Node 1, which is the tail now

Note that `node = prev` doesn't actually do anything but reassign the parameter, which is usually never a good idea

Comment: In main(), I called the method by, `list.reverseList(list.head);` And at the end of the `reverseList(Node node)` definition, I reseted the node to previous `(node=prev)`. So, here, doesn't It mean list.head = prev? Why will this not work?

Comment: Not sure I understand, but I see nowhere but the constructor that you've set `list.head`

Comment: In main(), I called the method by, list.reverseList(list.head); And at the end of the reverseList(Node node) definition, I reseted the node to previous (node=prev). So, here, doesn't It mean list.head = prev? Why will this not work?

Comment: As I said `node = prev` is not the same as explicitly putting `this.head = prev`

Comment: It won't work because all you did was reassign the reference of the parameter, not the instance variable of the class.... It's like expecting `Node iter = node;` and modifying iter to somehow affect `node`

Comment: @NiharikaEpuri Because Java is not pass-by-reference. The fallacy is right there in your title. Read the duplicate.

Comment: In java if reference is changed then won't the instance variable also change?

Comment: @NiharikaEpuri No, because Java is not pass-by-reference, as I have just told you, contrary to the assertion in your title, and as is clearly answered several times in the duplicate.

Comment: Ya got it. Thank alot :)

Comment: I wonder why this was down voted ? It answers "Why is the list not printing in the correct orde (3->2->1) after reversing the list?"

Answer (score 0):

Change `node = prev;` to `head = prev;` or better reverse the linked list by :

```
void reverseList(){

    Node iter = head;
    Node prev = null;

    while(iter!=null){

        Node currentNext = iter.next;
        iter.next = prev;
        prev = iter;
        iter = currentNext;
    }

    head = prev;
}
```